# document.referrer is not returning the previous page link

Tags: javascript, http, document

Actually, In chrome Incognito mode, I just try to search my page in google and navigate it to it.
When I check the document.referrer gives the current page link not a google.com which is not expected.

But when I goes back to the google and come again. Now document.referrer gives the google.com which is expected.

Can someone help me on this to resolve? document.referrer should always return the parent page even for the first time.

Comment: ```The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page directly (not through a link, but, for example, by using a bookmark).``` This is what they have mentioned on documentation.

Comment: @Nikkkshit yeah I went through the documentation.. my case is completely different. Its show’s current page path at first time..even don’t find the answer in google